# Provide/Inject typed refs in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to provide a typed ref from the parent and inject it into the child.

I'm not sure if I understand VueJS docs, but what's what I came up with.

```
import type  { Ref } from 'vue'
import type { InjectionKey } from 'vue'
import type DocumentSet from '@/types/DocumentSet'

const documentSet = Symbol() as InjectionKey<{
  documentSet: Ref<DocumentSet>,
  update: () => void
}>

export default documentSet
```

So, the task is to provide both typed object (documentSet in my case), and a function to update it.

Now, in the parent component I have this:

```
import dsKey from '@/injectionKeys/documentSet'
import type DocumentSet from '@/types/DocumentSet'

...

const documentSet = ref<DocumentSet | null>(null)

provide(dsKey, {
   documentSet,
   update: () => console.log('update')
})
```

And in the child component, I have this:

```
import dsKey from '@/injectionKeys/documentSet'

const ds = inject(dsKey)
const documentSet = ds?.documentSet
```

The thing is that it feels like I'm doing something wrong due to a lot of boilerplate code. For example, I couldn't understand why I restructure ds object, like this:

```
const { documentSet } = ds
```

Is it possible to shorten the code, instead of writing `ds?.documentSet`, especially if I'm sure the ds should be present (without it I don't render the child component)

In case I write it like this `const { documentSet } = inject(dsKey)`, the error would be:

`TS2339: Property 'documentSet' does not exist on type '{ documentSet: Ref ; update: () => void; } | undefined'.`

The idea came up because I wanted to eliminate the repetition in child components:

```
 <DocumentSetInfo
    :documentSet="documentSet"
  />
  <DocumentSetMemos
    :documentSet="documentSet"
  />
  <DocumentSetPrograms
    :documentSet="documentSet"
  />
  <DocumentSetPetition
    :documentSet="documentSet"
  />
  <DocumentSetPassRequests
    :documentSet="documentSet"
  />
  <DocumentSetReport
    :documentSet="documentSet"
  />
  <DocumentSetReceptionNotices
    :documentSet="documentSet"
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put it into a composable, which offers a provdide function that handles the provide, and a use* function which handles the inject:

```
const CurrentDocumentSetKey = Symbol() as InjectionKey<{
  documentSet: Ref<DocumentSet>,
  update: () => void
}>

export function provideCurrentDocumentSet(documentSet:DocumentSet, update: () => any){
  provide(CurrentDocumentSetKey, {documentSet, update})
}

export useCurrentDocumentSet(){
  const ds = inject(CurrentDocumentSetKey)
  if (!ds) throw new Error('No current DocumentSet provided')
  return ds
}
```

Now you can just call `provideCurrentDocumentSet()` in the parent, and all children just need to do

```
const {documentSet, update} = useCurrentDocumentSet()
```

You don't even have to export the InjectionKey, the components don't need to know about it.

(Vuetify does it the same way, for example [here](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/labs/VDataTable/composables/expand.ts))

Answer (score 0):

I think once the child component are being created, the default value of the inject is undefined. you can avoid this by adding a default value in the inject method. Like this:

```
// child.vue
<template>
  <br />

  <div>here in child{{ documentSet }}</div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { DocumentSet, documentSetKey } from "~/types/entity";

const { documentSet, update } = inject<DocumentSet>(documentSetKey, {
  documentSet: ref({ hey: "" }),
  update: () => {},
});
</script>
```

```
// entity.ts
import type { Ref } from "vue";
import type { InjectionKey } from "vue";

interface DocumentSet {
  documentSet: Ref<{ hey: string }>;
  update: () => void;
}

const documentSetKey = Symbol();

export { documentSetKey, DocumentSet };
```

But this is also bulky in terms of readability. IDK if this is what you're looking for.